# If a object that's bigger than the other collides with one thats more massive, who wins?

Tags: collision

So, let's say you've got two objects (A and B), A has a mass of 20 suns, while B has a mass of 10 suns, but A is only 10 suns in radius, while B is 30 suns in radius.

If both objects collided, who would survive and "win"?

Does it depend on density?
Or in mass?

Shouldn't the smaller but more dense object go into the core of B and extract all the mass or what?

EDIT: I do know that if two objects aren't going fast enough, they can bounce on collision, but in this example they're going at high speeds.

Comment: If they are stars neither wins, the combined object is neither A  or B but a new object you can call C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are stars then they may well combine. If you'd imagine them like bowling balls, then size has nothing to do with it! It's all down to momentum

P = mv - so the only factors affecting momentum are mass and velocity. Assuming they're both going the same speed, then the more massive one will "win" so to speak.

an air filled balloon v.s a bowling ball at the same velocity is also a good way to think about it!

If you want to get more complicated, then the effects of air resistance on larger objects can also come into play with your question. Hope this helps!